# I am trying to display a CountDownTimer on screen and I get "Only one looper can be created per thread" in my logcat

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm a beginner in Android programming. I'm trying to display a timer for an upgrade in my game to show how long the upgrade will be activated for. In my collision flag I call Looper.prepare and start my thread class as the logcat suggested I do. How would I get this to run on one looper?

Here is the snippet that starts the thread.

**BigGapUpgrade.java**

```java
public boolean playerCollectUpgrade(Player player){
       if(Rect.intersects(rectangle, player.getRectangle())){
           Looper.prepare();
           bigGapUpgradeHandler.start();
       }

        return Rect.intersects(rectangle, player.getRectangle());
   }
```

And here is my thread class

**BigGapUpgradeHandler.java**

```java
public class BigGapUpgradeHandler extends Thread {

    TimerTask scanTask;
    Timer timer = new Timer();

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Looper.prepare();
        scanTask = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {

            }
        };

        timer.schedule(scanTask, 0, 4000);


        CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(4000, 100) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long l) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onTick: ");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                timer.cancel();
                Log.i(TAG, "onFinish: ");
            }
        }.start();

        Looper.loop();
    }
}
```

After running it I get this error

```
W/System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: Only one Looper may be created per thread
```

**--Edit**

Here is the solution I came up with.

**-- Solution**

```java
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                CountDownTimer countDownTimer  = new CountDownTimer(5000,100) {
                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                        millis = millisUntilFinished/100;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {

                    }
                }.start();
            }
        });
```

Comment: The Main/UI Thread in Android is already a looper. so that `Looper.prepare();` in `playerCollectUpgrade(Player player)` is probably being called on the main thread; remove it.

Comment: Also, can you describe what you're trying to do a little better? It sounds like you have a count down you want to show the user, and there are easier ways to do that using an AsyncTask: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask

Comment: I removed it and still got the same error. I'll add a screenshot to the question. Basically, on the left hand side of the screen I have the sprite of the upgrade appear and I want to have a timer next to it showing how long the upgrade is active.

Comment: Yeah, you got the other error because you're implementing the looper thread incorrectly. Let me see if I can help...

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried reading the official docs but couldn't come up with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use LocalBroadcastManager for the timing to continuously in loop. Please check below code for for that :-

```
private void startTimer() {
    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(Constant.getInstance().ANSWER_TIME_IN_SECOND * 1000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            remaininTimeInMillies = millisUntilFinished;
            tvTimer.setText(getTime(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished))));
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Constant.getInstance().TIMER_RECEIVER);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(PatientDetailActivity.this).sendBroadcast(intent);
        }

    };
    countDownTimer.start();
}

private String getTime(int milliSec) {
    int minut = 0, second = 0;

    minut = milliSec / 60000;

    second = (milliSec - (minut * 60000)) / 1000;

    String strMinute = "", strSecond = "";
    if (minut < 10) {
        strMinute = "0" + String.valueOf(minut);
    } else {
        strMinute = String.valueOf(minut);
    }

    if (second < 10) {
        strSecond = "0" + String.valueOf(second);
    } else {
        strSecond = String.valueOf(second);
    }

    return strMinute + ":" + strSecond;
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(timerBroadcast, new IntentFilter(Constant.getInstance().TIMER_RECEIVER));
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(timerBroadcast);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Thanks and Hope that will help you

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Will give it a go and let you know

Comment: sure let me know if you have any query in that .. Thanks

Comment: I just come around to implement your solution and I can't really make sense of it. Could you provide a bit more explanation please? Thanks

Comment: Have you register receiver in your activity ? I have update answer please check it

Answer (score 0):

OK, So what you can do is just use a TimerTask. That creates it's own background thread for you do stuff:

```
// This TimerTask Updates the UI so it needs a reference to the Activity.
static class PowerUpTimerTask extends TimerTask
{

  WeakReference<AppCompatActivity> mActivity;
  long                             mInterval;
  long                             mPeriod;

  public PowerUpTimerTask(AppCompatActivity activity, long period, long interval)
  {
    mActivity = new WeakReference<>(activity);
    mInterval = interval;
    mPeriod = period;
  }

  @Override
  public void run()
  {
    AppCompatActivity activity = mActivity.get();
    if (activity != null)
    {
      final TextView timerTextView = activity.findViewById(R.id.timerTextView);

      mPeriod -= mInterval;

      if (mPeriod > 0)
      {
        // Set time remaining
        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
        {
          @Override
          public void run()
          {
            timerTextView.setText(String.valueOf(mPeriod));
          }
        });

      }
      else
      {
        // Out of time...clear the Text and stop the timer task.
        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
        {
          @Override
          public void run()
          {
            timerTextView.setText("");
          }
        });

        Log.d(TAG, "Timer done. Canceling.");
        cancel();
      }
    }
    else
    {
      // Cancel this timer task since we don't have a reference to
      // the Activity any more.
      Log.d(TAG, "Lost reference to Activity. Canceling.");
      cancel();
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can start your Timer task like so:

```
...
// Will count down from 10 by 1s.
mPowerUpTimerTask = new PowerUpTimerTask(this, powerUpTime, 1);

// Schedule for every second.
Timer t = new Timer();
t.scheduleAtFixedRate(mPowerUpTimerTask, 1000, 1000);
...
```

Here is a link to this running sample:

https://github.com/didiergarcia/TimerTaskExample

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I'm in the middle of adding fragments to my shop. Once I am done I will try your solution.

Comment: I tried your solution but couldn't get it to work. Also, I am drawing the text on a canvas rather than using a textview. My whole activity is pure java. When I instigate the powerUpTimerTask via my GamePanel class (where everything happens) it wont let me. I know it's looking for activity, but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Comment: I have come up with a solution. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Cool. You should post your solution so others can benefit.